# Google Chrome is not opening since update to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I just upgraded my system from Ubuntu 12.04 to 16.04.

Everything is fine, except Google Chrome is not opening.

Please suggest how I can fix this issue.

Comment: Try to open it from the terminal and post the error message. Maybe reinstalling it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling might solve your problem. First remove the package and the configuration files by typing the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable

rm ~/.config/google-chrome/ -rf
```

*Note:- The second command will remove all your bookmarks, settings etc.*

Then install Google Chrome. For that, follow these instructions:

1. Add key:

   ```
   wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. To set the repository, type the following command:

   ```
   echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
   ```
3. Install the Chrome browser package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
   ```

This should solve your problem.